# AngularJS change multiple partials per request

Tags: node.js, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am new in node.js and Angular and I am creating a web application.

At the moment I have the following design of my application - the screen is separeted by three columns - the left one is my menu and both middle and right columns are used to display the content. Sometimes when I click some of the elements in the menu I want to change only the middle column, if I click another menu element I want to change the partial in the right column and in other cases I want to change both middle and right columns per click in the menu.

I can't use ng:view because it doesn't allow me to use multiple ng:view elements. So I am wondering what is the best decision here. At the moment I am using ng:hide but it is not a good desicion. In the end I will have maybe 20 variables in my application which values I should update after every request.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Angular 1.x has a pretty limited router. Use [better alternative UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) which allows you to have multiple views.